# Llamada procedimiento almacenado SQL Server en Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Les escribo porque tengo el siguiente problema, favor si me pueden orientas o ayudar en una solucion.

Tengo el siguiente sp en sql server :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_PRUEBA1]
@registros int output

AS BEGIN

set @registros = 1+1

select @registros

END
```

---

Y quiero en Codeigniter recuperar el valor de esa variable de salida "@registros" pero no se me hace posible solo retorna null

Este es mi modelo :

```
public function obtenerNumero(){

$query = $this->db->query("DECLARE  @registros int EXEC SP_PRUEBA1 @registros = @registros OUTPUT SELECT    @registros");


return $query->result_array();

}
```

### Si estoy mal por favor su orientación agradeceré, muchas gracias.

Estimado Amilcar, ¿estoy bien?

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->trans_start();

$listo = $this->db->query("exec dbo.SP_PRUEBA1 (@registros);");
$parametro_fuera_query = $this->db->query('select @registros as registros;');

$this->db->trans_complete();

$parametro_fuera_fila = $this->db->fila();
$parametro_fuera_val = $this->registro;

echo $parametro_fuera_val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar

```
$this->db->query("llamada_sp('arg1','arg2');")
```

Si tiene parámetros fuera, tiene que envolverlo en una transacción de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->trans_start();

$listo = $this->db->query("llamada_sp('arg1','arg2',@parametro_fuera);");
$parametro_fuera_query = $this->db->query('select @parametro_fuera as parametro_fuera;');

$this->db->trans_complete();

$parametro_fuera_fila = $this->db->fila();
$parametro_fuera_val = $this->parametro_fuera;
```

Éxitos!

**Edito la respuesta basada en tu comentario**

Si vas a utilizar un `select` debes poner:

```
mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);
```

Sin embargo veo que tienes fallas en usar codeignator, lo mejor es que te pases por este enlace y así aprendas un poco más de uso, pues vas a estar saltando de problemas en problemas.   Te comparto como usar procedimientos almacenado en codeignator:

[Procedimientos almacenados en codeignator](https://kennybarrera.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/procedimientos-almacenados-usando-instrucion-select-en-codeigniter-3/)

Suerte!

Comment: $this->load->database();
$this->db->trans_start();

$listo = $this->db->query("exec dbo.SP_PRUEBA1 (@registros);");
$parametro_fuera_query = $this->db->query('select @registros as registros;');

$this->db->trans_complete();
$parametro_fuera_fila = $this->db->fila();
$parametro_fuera_val = $this->registro;
            
echo $parametro_fuera_val;

Comment: Me indica que debo declarar la variable @registros...